# Как сделать при наведении выпадающие ссылки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, меню

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы при наведении появлялся не цвет, а выпадали вниз ссылки.
Хочу применить в вертикальном меню.

```html
<html>
  <style type="text/css">
    .section { background:#ccc; }
    .layer { background:#ddd; }
    .section:hover img { border:2px solid #333; }
    .section:hover .layer { border:2px solid #F90; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="section">
    <img src="myImage.jpg" />
    <div class="layer">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну если мне память не изменяет, то на CSS такое нельзя сделать. Но можно JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```css
.section {
  background: #ccc;
}

.layer {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.section:hover img {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}

.section:hover .layer {
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <img src="myImage.jpg" />
  <div class="layer">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
```